# I'm looking for a word to describe someone who is so nice they impose on you

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

I'm looking for a word to describe someone who is so nice they impose on you.  For instance, someone who, despite being asked to leave a room as it is, comes in and makes the bed and "cleans up."  When confronted, says, "Oh, it only took a minute."  Well-intentioned but defiant.

Comment: an adjective or a noun? Or doesn't matter?

Comment: I'm easy, go for it.

Comment: *Overfriendly* or *imposing* doesn't work? I think imposing is the word  you're looking for, but you've already used it in the title.

Answer (score 2):

**well-intentioned** [collins dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/well-intentioned)

> If you say that a person or their actions are well-intentioned, you
>   mean that they intend to be helpful or kind but they are unsuccessful
>   or cause *problems*!

Comment: @NigelJ does the link "well-ententioned"  highlighted in red suffice?

Comment: See the Andrew Leach's top voted answer here - [new-attribution-rules](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5193/new-attribution-rules). "This is not acceptable because the source of the quote is not cited in plain text. It doesn't matter if the headword here is a link; the source — which is ODO in this case — must appear in plain text."

Comment: @PhilSweet aye aye

Answer (score 1):

It depends upon whether or not you want a negative connotation. If you do, then some possibilities might be ***meddlesome*** (or ***meddling***), ***do-gooder***, or ***intrusive***. If you do not want a negative connotation, then a single word might not be enough; you might need a fuller description to convey the notion that the person *means* well but unintentionally crosses the personal boundaries of others.

Comment: Meddlesome is good, but I'm looking for a word that incorporates her passive-aggressive approach to meddling.  Defiantly doing what she's been clearly asked not to do.

Comment: I hadn't picked up on the defiance element, of intentional vs. unintentional offense. Perhaps **disingenuous** would work? "Her disingenuous meddling" or something along those lines. As I said above, I can't think of any single word that will convey the subtleties and nuances that you're trying to convey.

Answer (score 1):

It may be too forceful a term, but I am reminded ever so strongly of the term ***['smother'](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/smother)*** here.

> 1.1 Make (someone) feel trapped and oppressed by acting in an overly protective manner towards them.
>   *‘it's time for you to leave the house—she'll smother you if you remain’*

Reference:
https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/smother

Answer (score 0):

## Answer

**unctuous**, according to [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/unctuous):

> *"Unctuous people or behaviour expresses too much praise, interest, friendliness, etc., in a way that is false and unpleasant"* [1](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/unctuous)

Another option could be **overzealous**, according to [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/overzealous):

> "too zealous : having or showing too much zeal : excessively eager, enthusiastic, or fervent"[2](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/overzealous)

## Appropriate source attribution

[1](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/unctuous) "Overzealous." Merriam-Webster.com. Accessed March 20, 2018. https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/overzealous.

[2](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/overzealous) (Definition of “unctuous” from the Cambridge Advanced Learner’s Dictionary & Thesaurus © Cambridge University Press)

Comment: It is customary to link to your reference so that others may follow it.

Comment: @NigelJ the little 1 at the end of the quote links to CD.

Comment: For the benefit of those of us with less than 20/20 vision may I suggest something just a little more obvious ?

Comment: Sure, I'll make it redundant (I'm used to using footnotes). You can click the names of the dictionaries to go to their respective pages.

Comment: Both Cambridge and MW provide cites, you just have to copy and paste them. Links are not satisfactory substitutes.

Comment: @PhilSweet links accompanied by names (in this case the names of the dictionaries) are sufficient. [Please read up on this page in the help section](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing)

Comment: See the Andrew Leach's top voted answer here - [new-attribution-rules](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5193/new-attribution-rules).  "This is not acceptable because the source of the quote is not cited in plain text. It doesn't matter if the headword here is a link; the source — which is ODO in this case — must appear in plain text." They way it reads at the moment seems okay, as I understand the rules"

Comment: @PhilSweet I see, thanks for bringing that to my attention.